Two Foreign Keys Relation To One Primary Key In Another Table in Spring Data JPA
I am using Spring Data JPA and Hibernate to create and map two tables PROCESS and STATEMENT, the STATEMENT table has two FK referring to id from the PROCESS table and I want to have a relationship between these two tables and from Process entity I want to have ability to find associated Statement records when inquiry tables,
so I implemented the below entities for this purpose:
Process:
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table( name = "PROCESS" )
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Process {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column( name = "start_date" )
    private LocalDateTime startDate;

    @Column( name = "end_date" )
    private LocalDateTime endDate;

    @Builder.Default
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "removalProcessId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
    private List<Statement> statements = new ArrayList<>();

}

And Statement:
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table( name = "STATEMENT" )
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode( callSuper = true )
public class Statement extends AuditableEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long  id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "validation_process_id", referencedColumnName = "ID" , nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey( name = "FK__VALIDATION_PROCESS_ID_TO_SECTION_REMOVAL_PROCESSES.ID" ))
    private Process validationProcessId;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "validation_status")
    private ValidationStatus validationStatus;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "removal_process_id", referencedColumnName = "ID" , nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey( name = "FK__REMOVAL_PROCESS_ID_TO_SECTION_REMOVAL_PROCESSES.ID" ))
    private Process  removalProcessId;

}

Now the question is my implementation ok and standard? is there any issue or problem in my design and implementation? if Yes, so I would appreciate it if you guide me
